# Riemann surface with $w=z-\sqrt{z^2-1}$ single-valued

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to find the Riemann surface that makes $w=z-\sqrt{z^2-1}$ single-valued, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: You could write $w = z - y$ and $y^2 = z^2-1$ and eliminate $y$ by groebner base methods. (I just did this with Macaulay 2).

Comment: Of course you do not need groebner bases here, just write $y = (z-w)$ and substitute $(z-w)^2 = z^2 - 1$. (I must have been a bit tired, when I wrote the comment above).